# How to mock Subsonic Dataset that is coming out of the Stored proc?

Tags: subsonic, moq

I am looking for code samples to mock dataset after stored proc call using Subsonic.

Here is my method.

```
public List<DistributionDetail> GetDistributionsForInvoice(string invoiceId)
    {
        List<DistributionDetail> result = new List<DistributionDetail>();
        StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("GetDistributions", this.dataProvider);
        sp.Command.AddParameter("InvoiceID", invoiceId, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);

        DataTable dt = sp.ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            DistributionDetail d    = new DistributionDetail();
            DateTime date           = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[2].ToString());
            d.DistributionId        = dr[0].ToString();
            d.DistributionAmount    = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1].ToString());
            d.DepositDate           = date.ToString(ApplicationConstants.DateFormat);
            d.LockboxNumber         = dr[3].ToString();
            d.BatchNumber           = dr[4].ToString();
            d.TransactionNumber     = dr[5].ToString();

            result.Add(d);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mock dataset"?

Answer (score 0):

In SubSonic 2.2, you can call [ExecuteTypedList](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/blob/master/SubSonic/ActiveRecord/StoredProcedure.cs#L318).

```
public List<DistributionDetail> GetDistributionsForInvoice(string invoiceId)
{
    List<DistributionDetail> result = new List<DistributionDetail>();
    StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("GetDistributions", this.dataProvider);
    sp.Command.AddParameter("InvoiceID", invoiceId, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);

    return sp.ExecuteTypedList<DistributionDetail>();
}
```

The column names from the stored procedure result set must match the property names on DistributionDetail.